# SQL data import in Pivot Table, wrong datatype

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-2013

Working with Excel 2013 Standard and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have created a pivot table with this connection:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=sqlserver;
       UID=xxx;PWD=yyy;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;
       WSID=CVH2014021;DATABASE=VH_Datawarehouse;

SELECT [Klantnummer]
      ,cast([Faktuurdatum] as datetime) as 'Faktuurdatum'
      ,[Grootboek_Transactie]
      ,[Grootboek_BTW]
      ,[Kostenplaats_Transactie]
      ,[LitersGetankt]
      ,[Netto_Euro_bedrag]
      ,[BTW_Euro_bedrag]
FROM [VH_Datawarehouse].[dbo].[ds_Selectie_Aanlevering_Tankgegevens]
WHERE (Faktuurdatum >= dateadd(dd,-120,getdate()))
  and GegevensBron = 'Shell'
```

The columns Grootboek_Transactie / Grootboek_BTW / Kostenplaats_Transactie are all int fields, but in Excel they appear as Currency fields. I can change the columns in Excel to Standard or Values, but after a refresh of the connection, the columns change back to currency values.

I changed the driver name from SQL Server to SQL Server Native Client 10.0, as this could have impact, but then also my datetime field Faktuurdatum appears as currency.

How can I fix this.

The values as currency part is solved.
It works also for the date part, but Excel doesn't see this as dates, but as text.

Comment: How did you set format in Excel? If you go `Field Settings`->`Number Format`, this setting should be preserved after refresh.

Comment: Checking, or unchecking, this field has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i hope this will you

```
select * ,
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE( Grootboek_Transactie ,CHAR(9),' ')
        ,CHAR(13),' ')
      ,CHAR(10),' ')
    ,CHAR(32),' ')
  ,CHAR(34),' ') AS Grootboek_Transacti_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in your SQL output, You have the last Column Grootboek_Transacti_1 ,,,,paste this in Excel. It will be as it is.(No Currency Conversion is Expected)